# Combine node.js rest api's and angular on same server

Tags: node.js, angular

We first developed REST api's using node.js and have that running on a VPS. We now have developed an Angular web app to display data that comes in via a mobile app that calls some of the REST api's and then updates the data by calls back to other REST API's. Running the Angular app on the localhost was able to successfully call the REST api's.

We want to combine both applications on the same server. After searching around it seemed that we could add commands to the REST api server.js to pass urls that didn't meet the REST api path to Angular. Code snippet is below:

```
// API verison
var apiVersion = '/v1'

var fs ;
var https ;

// Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// MongoDB
...

// Express
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Routes
app.use(apiVersion, require('./routes/api'));

// Start server
fs = require('fs')
https = require('https')
https.createServer({
     key: fs.readFileSync('...'),
     cert: fs.readFileSync('...')
}, app)
.listen(443, function () {
  console.log('HTTPS Server running on default port 443')
});
  
// Pass request to angular?
app.use(function(req, res) {
  var path = require('path');
  res.sendfile(path.resolve('/home/.../index.html')); // but not getting anything
});
```

The REST api's still work but when directing a browser to  'mydomain.net' I just get a blank page. I don't see any errors on the node/error logs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the below answer help  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. Use static content to send from the dist folder and rest will work fine. I have added two reference in case you might need them to refer.

```
var apiVersion = '/v1'

const fs = require('fs')
const https = require('https');
const path = require('path')

// Dependencies
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// MongoDB
...

// Express
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Pass request to angular?
app.use('path', express.static(path.resolve('your path should be correct')));

// Routes
app.use(apiVersion, require('./routes/api'));

// Start server
https.createServer({
     key: fs.readFileSync('...'),
     cert: fs.readFileSync('...')
}, app)
.listen(443, function () {
  console.log('HTTPS Server running on default port 443')
});
```

Check [here1](https://sidhu-dreamer.medium.com/deploy-angular-app-in-node-server-express-static-rest-api-method-in-the-same-port-2c8b5a39ebce) or [here2](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/how-to-develop-and-build-angular-app-with-nodejs-e24c40444421) for more details, there are simple steps to follow.

Comment: Apoorva - Thanks. I haven't gotten the Angular code to display the web page, but I see the the index.html is being loaded by the browser. I am assuming there is some problem with the Angular code at this point so I will mark this as the answer.